# Returning Image from Web.API and Displaying using an img tag

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that returns an image retrieving a byte array from an image stored in the database as varbinary(max). But the image is NOT getting displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Web API

```
        [Route("service/products/{id?}/thumbnail")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetPiThumbnail(long id)
        {
            if (id == 0) return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            var data = _productsRepository.Get(a => a.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault().ThumbnailImage;

            if (data == null) return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return response;
        }
```

Here is the snippet from the razor file in an ASP.NET MVC app to show the image returned by the above Web API -

```
      <div><img src="../service/products/378728/thumbnail" /></div>
```

Comment: What HTTP status code are you getting back? 200? 404?

Comment: Is `_productsRepository.Get(a => a.ProductId == id).SingleOrDefault().ThumbnailImage` a byte array?

Comment: Are you able to put a breakpoint in your Web API code and see if you are actually getting data returned from your repository call?

Comment: HttpStatusCode.OK is returning 200 in response. I checked that it is returning data and it is byte array.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ContentType to a image type, like MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg") or whatever format you're returning?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it didn't work. I am certain that it is because of the format of the byte array that is saved in the database. There is nothing wrong with this code. Thanks for all your help.